# delete a folder and its content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, delete-file

I just followed [this tutorial](http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2015/04/delete-all-files-and-subdirectories.html) to delete a folder and its content

```
    public ActionResult Product_Delete()
    {
        string idnumber = "07";

        string path1 = @"~/Content/Essential_Folder/attachments_AR/" + idnumber;

        DirectoryInfo attachments_AR = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(path1));
        EmptyFolder(attachments_AR);
        Directory.Delete(path1);

        ....
    } 

    private void EmptyFolder(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {

        foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdirectory in directory.GetDirectories())
        {
            EmptyFolder(subdirectory);
            subdirectory.Delete();
        }

     }
```

But using this its deleting all the contnet in `07` folder, but its not deleting the `07` folder finally.

I'm getting error in this  line `Directory.Delete(path1);`

Once I debug I can see run time error with below message

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\~\Content\Essential_Folder\attachments_AR\07'.

but path1 value is `~/Content/Essential_Folder/attachments_AR/07`

Comment: In addition to the answers - `Directory.Delete(attachments_AR.FullName);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `Directory.Delete` cannot recognize `~` in the path.

You need to convert it to an absolute path using `Server.MapPath()` like you did it here:

```
DirectoryInfo attachments_AR = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(path1));
```

You may also want to convert it once, and use in both methods:

```
public ActionResult Product_Delete()
{
    string idnumber = "07";

    string mappedPath1 = Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Essential_Folder/attachments_AR/" + idnumber);

    DirectoryInfo attachments_AR = new DirectoryInfo(mappedPath1));
    EmptyFolder(attachments_AR);
    Directory.Delete(mappedPath1);

    ....
}
```

**By the way**, there is absolutely no need to remove files manually. You can use

```
public ActionResult Product_Delete()
{
    string idnumber = "07";
    string mappedPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Essential_Folder/attachments_AR/" + idnumber);

    Directory.Delete(mappedPath, true);
}
```

which will remove all folders, subfolders and files recursively, and then will remove directory itself.

Comment: Yeah that can optimise my code, I just looking for something like that thanks lot

Answer (score 2):

you cannot delete a directory by giving its physical path. from a web application using `Directory.Delete()`, so you have to convert it into absolute path by using `Server.MapPath()`

Use :  `Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath(path1));`

Or you can use Like the following without using `EmptyFolder()` method :

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(path1)); 
dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList().ForEach(file=>file.Delete()); 
// will delete all files in the folder and its sub folder
//so you don't need to iterate each sub folder and files in it
Directory.Delete(Server.MapPath(path1));
```

Comment: thanks this answer also correct , but @Yeldar answered firstly

Comment: It's okay, nop; i have updated my answer. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

you should delete the directly using full path instead of relative path. Try with

```
Directory.Delete(attachments_AR.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take separate path of the folder in variable and pass this variable in  Directory.Delete(.) Like :

```
var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Test");
DirectoryInfo attachments_AR = new DirectoryInfo(path);
Directory.Delete(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use method from Directory class ([MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public static void Delete(
    string path,
    bool recursive
)
```

Your code will be cleaner and simplier but much more important is that when building path manually you can achive path long limit. I get issue like this and solution was use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution what I did and it is deleting the root folder too:

```
public ActionResult Product_Delete()
    {
        string idnumber = "07";

        string path1 = @"~/Content/Essential_Folder/attachments_AR/" + idnumber;

        DirectoryInfo attachments_AR = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(path1));
        EmptyFolder(attachments_AR);

        if (attachments_AR.Exists && IsDirectoryEmpty(attachments_AR.FullName))
            attachments_AR.Delete();


    }

    private static void EmptyFolder(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdirectory in directory.GetDirectories())
        {
            EmptyFolder(subdirectory);
            subdirectory.Delete();
        }
    }

    public static bool IsDirectoryEmpty(string path)
    {
        return !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any();
    }
```